# How to hyperlink text to an external website on Wordpress Fancybox images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to link these fancy box images to a website externally.

For example: http://www.dramaticsnyc.com/stylistsandlocations/

Click on one of the stylists and the image pops up. On the bottom it says click here to read and write reviews. When you click on it, it doesnt go to the page, it gets stuck on the same page. How can I make it link to the site on the hyper link? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the code I am currently using for each picture (put this code in fancygallery caption):

`<div style="display: none;">
 <div id="hover-image_0">
  <a class="fancyframe" href="http://www.reviewmenyc.com">Click here to write and read reviews! Review Me NYC</a>
 </div>
</div>`

It only links to the site internally not externally. If you click on the link, its supposed to go to www.reviewmenyc.com but its staying under www.dramaticsnyc.com. What do I have to do the change this? I am not the greatest but I can learn and I know my way around.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="’fancyframe’" href="’http://www.reviewmenyc.com’">Click here to write and read reviews! Review Me NYC</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a class="fancyframe" href="http://www.reviewmenyc.com">Click here to write and read reviews! Review Me NYC</a>
```

There is no need for the extra `'` in the `class` and the `href`

Also, instead of changing the page location, you might want to just open a new tab. If so, use this:

```
<a target="_blank" class="fancyframe" href="http://www.reviewmenyc.com">Click here to write and read reviews! Review Me NYC</a>
```

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work. It seems to add the extra ' on its own.

Comment: it still says page not found when I click on the text. It opens up a new page but still stays local..

Comment: @user2880613 when i edited the html on the page it worked. Let me check once more.

Comment: It goes to this page: http://www.dramaticsnyc.com/stylistsandlocations/%E2%80%99http:/www.reviewmenyc.com%E2%80%99

Comment: @user2880613 that is because your html still has the `'` in the `""`: `<a class="’fancyframe’" href="’http://www.reviewmenyc.com’">Click here to write and read reviews! Review Me NYC</a>` Take those out.